Is a density matrix still positive semidefinite after applying a projection operator?
Suppose we have a density operator $\hat{\rho}$ and a projection operator $\hat{\Pi}$, are the matrices
$$\hat{\rho}'=\hat{\Pi}\hat{\rho}\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}$$
and
$$\hat{\rho}''=(\hat{I}-\hat{\Pi})\hat{\rho}(\hat{I}-\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger})$$
also positive semidefinite (i.e they can be renormalised to give physical density matrices)

Yes: For $P$ positive semi-definite, $XPX^\dagger$ is also positive, since
$$
\langle \phi\vert XPX^\dagger \vert\phi\rangle = \langle \phi'\vert P\vert\phi'\rangle \ge 0
$$
with $\vert\phi'\rangle:=X^\dagger \vert\phi\rangle$.

great thanks, just to clarify, $
\langle \phi\vert XPX^\dagger \vert\phi\rangle \ge 0
$ $\forall \vert\phi\rangle$ is equivalent to saying $P$ has only positive eigenvalues?

My issue is that applying such a transformation in a simulation leaves me with a state that has negative eigenvalues, although im pretty certain this must be numeric.

@AdrienAmour yes (well it is equivalent to saying that $XPX^\dagger$ has non-negative eigenvalues!). if you have numerical issues it could also come from how you're defining the projection, because if you haven't normalized it properly it could be that $\hat{I}-\hat{Pi}$ goes negative (ie, make sure that $\hat{\Pi}^2=\hat{\Pi}$ and not $\hat{\Pi}^2\propto \hat{\Pi}$); or you can check that your state itself before the projection is indeed positive

@AdrienAmour In complex vector spaces, <x|A|x> >= 0 is equivalent to saying that A is hermitian and only has non-negative eigenvalues.

@AdrienAmour How negative are they?

@QuantumMechanic Normalization should not matter: Nowhere any property of $X$ is needed.

@NorbertSchuch you are absolutely correct, my mistake

@Norbert Schuch Alright thanks that answers my original question

@NorbertSchuch  to be more specifiic, my system is  two cavity modes and an atom. The projector is $\hat{I}{1}\otimes\hat{I}{2}\otimes\hat{I}{atom}-|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes\hat{I}{atom}$  (i.e the projector out of all states with no photons in the cavity). This is transforming my density matrix from positive semidefinite matrix to one with negative eigenvalues (of up to -1E-3).

@AdrienAmour Apparently this is not what you are doing.

@NorbertSchuch are you suggesting this is a coding error?
